# How can i stop my text css from over-riding my form on my blog?

Tags: css, forms, text, sidebar

Currently Im using the below css for all of my text. However it is changing my form text on my blog (which I don't want it to do.) How can i set a new style for this blog-sidebar-form. I just want to center the text and make it bold, etc.

http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/blog/

```
p { 
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Regular", "Helvetica Neue Regular", ``"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: 300; 
  max-width: 550px; 
  color: #4d4d4d; 
  text-align: left; 
  line-height: 175%; 
  letter-spacing: 1px; 
  word-spacing: 0px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 
}
```

Comment: Instead of linking to your site, can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probable do something like this for the blog.
So you can overwrite the base style.

```
p { 
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Regular", "Helvetica Neue Regular", ``"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: 300; 
  max-width: 550px; 
  color: #4d4d4d; 
  text-align: left; 
  line-height: 175%; 
  letter-spacing: 1px; 
  word-spacing: 0px; 
  margin-top: 20px; 
}
p.blog {text-align: right/*and other code*/}

<p class="blog">  This paragraph will be right-aligned. </p>/*you should give all the p in your blog the blog element*/
```

Good luck with it.

Comment: You could try to add some style code to the html file. This had a higher priority than the css file.

Comment: have you tried it like this? <p style="color: sienna; margin-left: 20px">
  This is a paragraph
</p>

Answer (score 0):

Give the form a class, or if it is the only form, I think you can just put form. From there, I believe you can give a negation pseudo class:

```
    :not(form){text-align:center; font-weight:bold; /*any other css you would like to enter. make sure you copy the entire line. this is a comment so you can delete it.*/}
```

Or maybe you could affect the inputs of the form:

```
    form input{ text-align:center; font-weight:bold; }
```

I hope they work.

Comment: Yeah so give the form a class and put all the classes separated by commas in between the parenthesis. That will solve your problem.

Comment: All the classes in your css document. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I'll do it for you and post the answer later. Please wait.

Comment: please wait, I will have it for you in a few hours.

Comment: Jeff, when I was trying this on my own, the Form input { css in here } worked for me perfectly. Try doing it again

Comment: now I'm trying to add some space (margin or padding?) after the "subscribe" button, and also space after the RSS icon / before the "Subscribe in a reader" text